# Changing values in Java

Tags: java, debugging, junit

I am trying to pass in values to the `setAmount()` method in my Bill class and make sure that they can be changed in the method. I am using JUnit to test the method. I'm not sure what is meant by a privacy leak in the method. I made sure there were no privacy leaks in the constructor but not sure how else I would fix it. The line that fails is:

`assertTrue( b1.setAmount(m2));` in `testSetAmountOKWithPrivacyLeak()`

```
@Test
public void testSetAmountOKWithPrivacyLeak()
{
    Date d1 = new Date( 3,4,2020);
    Money m1 = new Money(10);
    Bill b1 = new Bill( m1, d1, "fred");

    Money m2 = new Money(11);
    // Not paid so we can chane it successfully
    assertTrue( b1.setAmount(m2));
    // Check money changed. 
    assertTrue( b1.getAmount().equals( m2));

    //Change money  in n2 and verify it has not changed. 
    m2.setMoney(12,0);
    assertFalse( b1.getAmount().equals(m2));
}

//Change the amount owed.
//If already paid returns false and does not change the amount owed else changes 
//the amount and returns true.
public boolean setAmount (Money amount) {
    if (isPaid() == false) {
        amount = new Money(amount);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

//returns true if bill is paid, else false
public boolean isPaid () {
    return (paidDate != null);
}
```

Comment: What does `isPaid()` contain?

Comment: Don't you want to return false if isPaid() is true?

Comment: Added isPaid() to the question.

Comment: it should be if the bill is not paid: isPaid() == false and the amount doesn't change. if it is paid else changes the amount and returns true

Comment: @JamieWest, that seems to contradict the comment `//If already paid returns false and does not change the amount`

Comment: oh got it. I misunderstood.